# How can Acrobat features be controlled from within LaTeX?

Tags: pdf, revtex, acrobat

I needed to install the package `xpatch` which fixes a glitch in `revtex4` regarding cross-referencing. However, now, every time I compile a LaTeX file the produced PDF document has the annoying sideband and is 76.9% in size. What are the instructions in the code of the `.tex` document that would cause the sideband to disappear and the size of the page to be, say, 150%?

Comment: I think this has been addressed in the comments of Werner's answer, but you should really be using `revtex4-1`. I am curious though; what is your reason for using REVTeX? If you're submitting to a journal, then chances are you can't use `xpatch` anyway. If you can use one, alternatives to REVTeX are less likely to conflict with newer packages like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will this help?

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
pdfstartview={FitH \hypercalcbp{\paperheight-\topmargin-0in
-\headheight-\headsep}
}}
```

Comment: Thanks Harish, that does work to make page larger. However, the sideband is still there.

Comment: Pl. refer to the documentation of hyperref for detailed control of such things.

Answer (score 10):

In order to remove the sidebar, use the [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) setting:

```
pdfpagemode=UseNone
```

In order to restore the regular "Fit page width" zoom view at startup, use:

```
pdfstartview=FitH
```

Combining these gives you

```
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\hypersetup{pdfstartview=FitH,pdfpagemode=UseNone}
```

If you're interested in a 150% start view, you can use

```
pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1.5}
```

where `null null` refers to `left top` coordinates of the zoom level. That is, the top-left corner of the page in this case. For more on Acrobat menu/configurations using `hyperref`, see section [3.6 PDF display and information options](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.html#x1-100003.6).

Comment: Wonder if this is the place to mention it -- xpatch seems to modify revtex4 in an unpredictable manner. The document was compiling properly until suddenly something happened and it started giving me tons of errors regarding cross-referencing. The culprit was \affiliation{}. As soon as I removed it all went well. Also, even prior to this problem it turned out impossible to use \textbf{} in the text of the sections.

Comment: @ganzewoort: But setting up a minimal `revtex4` document *without* `xpatch` and using `\affiliation{}` also gives errors, so I don't think `xpatch` is the cause. I am able to include `\textbf{...}` inside a sectioning command without problem. Note that using certain formatting in sectioning commands with `hyperref` present could be problematic. Not only do these commands end up in the ToC (which should be treated with care), but they also end up as bookmarks, which is ASCII only. Hence the macro `\texorpdfstring{<tex>}{<pdf>}` provided by `hyperref` to circumvent this.

Comment: OK, tried it with revtex4-1. That fixes the problem with \affiliation{}.

Comment: Back again. The \affiliation{} problem is fixed with revtex4-1 but only with fancyhdr. Otherwise gives cross-referencing error.

Comment: \textbf{} problem persists in both cases.

Comment: Werner, I've never had problems with \affiliation{} and/or \textbf{} before (before using xpatch). Interestingly, it was working pretty well (except for \texbf{}) with xpatch until, as I said, something happened without me changing anything and the whole thing got messed up.

Comment: @ganzewoort: If this seems unfixable and you think it may be related to `xpatch`, ask a [follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-post-a-follow-up-question-why-and-how) - they are more than welcome! Be sure to include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem (as opposed to code snippets).

Comment: For some reason can't reproduce the problem in a minimal example.

Comment: Not the \affiliation{} problem. The \textbf{} problem shows up in a MWE as well. Will post a follow-up question to sort this out. Thanks.