# Apparent Instability in REVTeX4 After Adding xpatch Package

Tags: revtex, xpatch

This is a follow-up question to [How can Acrobat features be controlled from within LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44913/how-can-acrobat-features-be-controlled-from-within-latex)

It seems that `xpatch` package makes REVTeX unstable and even appears to turn off some of its features. Thus, instead of making an Acrobat 5 document it makes Acrobat 9 if both are installed. More worrisome, however, is the sudden change of behavior for unknown reasons. I was working with a document and all went just fine but all of a sudden my WinEdt refused to compile it. Numerous errors showed cross-referencing problems. It turned out the culprit is `\affiliation{}`. As soon as I removed it, the problem disappeared. Unfortunately, I cannot demonstrate it in a MWE because it doesn't show up there. What shows up in a MWE is another problem---`\section{}` does not accept `\textbf{}`:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,twoside]{revtex4}

\usepackage{xpatch}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@ssect@ltx}{\@xsect}{\edef\@currentlabelname{#8}\@xsect}{}{}%     Patch \<section>*
\xpatchcmd{\@sect@ltx}{\@xsect}{\edef\@currentlabelname{#8}\@xsect}{}{}% Patch \<section>
\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref

\hypersetup{pdfstartview=FitH,pdfpagemode=UseNone}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\affiliation{Affiliation}

\maketitle

%\section*{FirstSection--$E \times H$ vs.$\ \textbf{E} \times \textbf{H}$} 
\section*{FirstSection} 

\label{sec:marker1}
In \nameref{sec:marker2} it is stated that \ldots

\section*{SecondSection} \label{sec:marker2}
You can also see in \nameref{sec:marker1} that \ldots
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the above example works as long as `\section*{FirstSection--$E \times H$ vs.$\ \textbf{E} \times \textbf{H}$}`, containing 
`\textbf{}` characters, is remmed out. If you un-rem it and instead rem out `\section*{FirstSection}` the compilation crashes.

Do you think I should live with it and have the affiliation follow the author in `\author{}` and instead of `\textbf{Something}` should use `\bf Something \rm` instead or there are radical solutions of this instability, if at all?

Comment: The patching should use `\protected@edef` rather than just `\edef`.

Comment: That indeed takes care of the \textbf{} problem but doesn't solve the \affiliation{} one.

Comment: It appears the patch doesn't like long abstracts with separate paragraphs. It would accept such, as long as \affiliation{} is remmed out.

Comment: The `\affiliation` macro is not 'long'. That has nothing to do with `xpatch`: you see the same without loading it. Probably the author of REVTeX does not expect affiliations to be large blocks of text.

Comment: As noted in the answers and comments in the question that you reference, you should not be using `revtex4`, but rather `revtex4-1`. This may seem like an incremental difference, but there's something like a 10 year gap between the two!

Comment: I was referring to what's within \begin{abstract} \end{abstract}. It seems that sometimes the length of text there matters and for some reason corrupts \affiliation{}. Anyway, after rewriting the abstract, making it shorter, compilation goes smoothly so far. By the way, revtex4-1 capitalizes all letters in \section*{}, starred or not starred. Wonder if that's what's intended or there's a way to change it?

Comment: @ganzewoort: If you want to make sure that I read your replies, make sure you use my name (type `@` followed with my name and it'll give you an auto-complete). Do *not* use `revtex4`. If you're submitting to a journal this will only cause problems. If you're not submitting to a journal, just don't use REVTeX. It's a real pain when you want to do anything special.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\affiliation` macro is not 'long'. That has nothing to do with `xpatch`: you see the same without loading it. Probably the author of REVTeX does not expect affiliations to be large blocks of text.